# Is it by jurisdiction that every country have to publish statistics of COVID-19 related statistics?

Tags: jurisdiction, covid-19, public-health

I have found that the Philippines has published the COVID-19 related statistics in accordance with [Section 28, Article II of the 1987 Constitution](https://www.officialgazette.gov.ph/constitutions/1987-constitution/), [Section 7, Article III of the same Constitution](https://www.officialgazette.gov.ph/constitutions/1987-constitution/), [Republic Act No. 10173 or the Data Privacy Act of 2012](https://www.privacy.gov.ph/data-privacy-act/), [Executive Order No. 2, series of 2016](https://www.officialgazette.gov.ph/2016/07/23/executive-order-no-02-s-2016/), and [the Republic Act No. 11332](https://www.officialgazette.gov.ph/2019/04/26/republic-act-no-11332/).

Is it by jurisdiction that every country has to publish COVID-19-related statistics? Otherwise, if it is not by the jurisdiction to provide these statistics, then it would be possible that a country would not even provide these publications? Furthermore, is there an article that specifically discusses this matter?

What is the reason why almost every countries are compelled to provide the COVID-19 related statistics?

Comment: It is not quite clear what you mean by the phrase 'by jurisdiction". A jurisdiction is an area within which law operates. It can be a physical, geographic area. or it can be a subject area. It is not the same thing  as a law.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some countries may be required by **their own** laws to publish such statistics. Those countries whch are WHO members are, I believe, strongly requested to provide such information to the WHO, who will normally publish it.

But to the best of my understanding, no outside law or force **requires** any country to publish or even collect COVID statistics. Many, indeed most, countries do so, apparently thinking that it is good policy to do so.